# Use a TableViewController with Prototyped Cells Multiple Times in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a tabview in Xamarin IOS where the user will be able to add new tabs by pressing a button. I want all of the tabs to be created from a single tableview controller that I have created in the story board with several prototype cells on it. When I try to create a tab using the view controller it loads the correct number of cells, but all of them are blank. I don't get any kind of error either.

Here is the code for one of my prototype cells:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace NewEPA
{
    public partial class ACUnitCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("AC");
        public static readonly UINib Nib;
        static ACUnitCell()
        {
            Nib = UINib.FromName("AC", NSBundle.MainBundle);

        }
        public ACUnitCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public ACUnitCell(string cellId) : base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the tableview controller:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NewEPA
{
    public partial class OptionConfigurationTableController : UITableViewController
    {

        static NSString ACCellId = new NSString("AC");
        public OptionConfigurationTableController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
        public OptionConfigurationTableController()
        {
            TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(ACUnitCell), ACCellId);
        }


        private OptionSource dataSource;
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            ProjectObject currentProject = new ProjectObject();



            dataSource = new OptionSource(currentProject);



            TableView.Source = dataSource;
            TableView.ReloadData();

        }




    }





    public class OptionSource : UITableViewSource
    {


        private const int AC_UNITS = 0, DUCT_WORK = 1, INSULATION = 2, THERMOSTAT = 3, ZONES = 4, ROOF = 5, ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS = 6;
        protected string cellIdentifier = "";
        static NSString ACCellId = new NSString("AC");
        protected string[] SectionNames = new string[] { "AC Units", "Duct Work", "Insulation", "Thermostat", "Zones", "Roof", "Additional Options"};

        public OptionSource(ProjectObject currentOption)
        {

        }


        public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 7;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            //include switch statement to figure out which section has however many rows. set to 4 for testing
            return 4;
        }


        public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return SectionNames[section];
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            switch(indexPath.Section)
            {
                case AC_UNITS:
                    cellIdentifier = "AC";
                    ACUnitCell cell0 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ACCellId) as ACUnitCell;
                    if (cell0 == null)
                        cell0 = new ACUnitCell(ACCellId);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell0;
                case DUCT_WORK:
                    cellIdentifier = "DuctWork";
                    DuctCell cell1 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as DuctCell;
                    if (cell1 == null)
                        cell1 = new DuctCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell1;
                case INSULATION:
                    cellIdentifier = "InsulationWork";
                    InsulationCell cell2 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as InsulationCell;
                    if (cell2 == null)
                        cell2 = new InsulationCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell2;
                case THERMOSTAT:
                    cellIdentifier = "ThermostatWork";
                    ThermostatCell cell3 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ThermostatCell;
                    if (cell3 == null)
                        cell3 = new ThermostatCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell3;
                case ZONES:
                    cellIdentifier = "ZoneWork";
                    ZoneCell cell4 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as ZoneCell;
                    if (cell4 == null)
                        cell4 = new ZoneCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell4;
                case ROOF:
                    cellIdentifier = "RoofWork";
                    RoofCell cell5 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as RoofCell;
                    if (cell5 == null)
                        cell5 = new RoofCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell5;
                case ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS:
                    cellIdentifier = "OtherOptionWork";
                    OtherOptionCell cell6 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as OtherOptionCell;
                    if (cell6 == null)
                        cell6 = new OtherOptionCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell6;

                    //i addeed in this default case so all paths would return a cell, but if the code here executes it's gonn eff stuff up
                    //it should never execute though...
                default:
                    cellIdentifier = "OtherOptionWork";
                    OtherOptionCell cell7 = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as OtherOptionCell;
                    if (cell7 == null)
                        cell7 = new OtherOptionCell(cellIdentifier);
                    //code to populate cell
                    return cell7;
            }
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 80;
        }

    }
```

Finally, this is the code I'm using in the tabcontroller to create the first tab:

```
namespace NewEPA
{
    public partial class OptionTabController : UITabBarController
    {
        OptionConfigurationTableController tab1;
        //tracks how many options are being used. starts out with one option by default
        int count = 1;
        //option limit sets limit on how many options can be created. default 5
        const int optionLimit = 5;

        public OptionTabController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {

            //creates single option tab
            tab1 = new OptionConfigurationTableController()
            {
                Title = "Option " + count
            };
            var tabs = new OptionConfigurationTableController[] {tab1};

            ViewControllers = tabs;

            count++;

        }
```

I just can't figure out why all the cells are blank. Everything seems to work fine seeing as how I don't get any errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the part with the Tabs but to fix the empty cells just remove this line:

```
TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(ACUnitCell), ACCellId);
```

As you are using Prototypes cells and if you set the ReuseIdentifier in the Prototype cells in the Storyboard you don't need it.

**A few things:**

Since you are using a `UITableViewController` you don't need to define a separate `UITableViewSource` you just need to override the same methods in your `OptionConfigurationTableController` class.

In `NumberOfSections` is safer if you return `SectionNames.Length` so in your `TitleForHeader` method you don't reach a `IndexOutOfRangeException`

To dequeue the cell you can use the static Key from the cell

changing this:

```
static NSString ACCellId = new NSString("AC");
.....
.....
tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ACCellId) as ACUnitCell;
```

for this:

```
tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ACUnitCell.Key, indexPath) as ACUnitCell;
```

Also notice I am using the method overload with the indexPath.

**UPDATE**

When working with Prototypes Cells in the StoryBoard the cell registration is made right in the designer.

Select the prototype cell and in the property tab update both the **Class** and the **identifier** with the name of your cell class.

It will look something like this:

[image]

Not relevant but here's the code of my CustomCell:

```
public partial class LeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("LeTableViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    static LeTableViewCell()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("LeTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    protected LeTableViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: I did everything you suggested, but when i used tableView.DequeueReusableCell(ACUnitCell.Key, indexPath) as ACUnitCell;   I got the following error: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier AC - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

Comment: @user1328147 that message refer to the "if you set the ReuseIdentifier in the Prototype cells" part of my answer. Updating original answer